# Dynamic allocated memory not aligned in SSE

Tags: c++, sse, simd, avx

Here's code which works normally:

```
char a[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
     a[i] = 0;
__m128i x = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *) a);
```

But if I dynamically allocate memory, VS 2013 will interrupt:

```
char *a = new char[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
     a[i] = 0;
__m128i x = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *) a);
```

How can I use both dynamic memory and aligned load instruction?

Comment: I think I totally misunderstood the question. Is there an error message or is the memory actually not aligned as desired?

Comment: The second one interrupt if I use the aligned load instruction.

Comment: I checked your code and it work fine on my console application. No errors.

Comment: No syntax errors. But still interrupt.

Answer (score 2):

Beacuse of sizeof is returning the size of a char pointer: 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You could either manipulate the `new` operator to return aligned memory (which might not be the best idea maintainance-wise), or you might allocate more memory and just operate on the aligned part of it. If, for instance, you need an alignment on an 8-byte even address, allocate 8 bytes more and work on an aligned pointer as follows.

```
char* a;
uintptr_t unaligned = (uintptr_t)a;
uintptr_t aligned = ( unaligned % 8 ) ? unaligned : ( unaligned % 8 ) + 8;
char* a_aligned = (char*)aligned;
```

The type `uintptr_t` is defined in `stdint.h`.